# Convert timestamp to local timezone in React or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I'm getting a timestamp from an API that uses the UTC timezone and my timezone is UTC+2 I am also using [timeago-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeago-react) package to display time ago for certain data generated by the API

```
const timestamp = blocks && blocks.block.timestamp; // getting data from API
let time = new Date(timestamp);
<p className="text-sm font-light">
 <TimeAgo datetime={time} locale="en_US" />
</p>
```

The issue I'm having is that the API is returning a timestamp of 11AM and my since my timezone is UTC+2 it's 1PM for me, the issue here is that 11AM UTC = 1PM for users with UTC+2 timezone but on time-ago it shows that the data has been generated 2hours ago which is incorrect. It was generated the moment I called that API.

Is there any workaround for this? So that it automatically calculates the time and converts it to whatever timezone the user has

Comment: what is the value of `time` that you are setting?

Comment: Check https://github.com/hustcc/timeago.js/issues/122

Comment: What is the value for *timestamp*? Without knowing that, any advice is based on guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys, after doing some research I was able to achieve it with vanilla JS using this:

```
  const fixDate = (date) => {
    let dateLocal = new Date(date);
    let newDate = new Date(
      dateLocal.getTime() - dateLocal.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
    );
    return newDate;
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
With moment.js you will be able to get the user timezone e.g 'America/Los_Angeles' and convert any existing timestamp to the specified timezone. Much more readable and maintain-able compared to using JS Date.

In your case the code should be something like this

```
var timezone = moment.tz.guess();
var now = moment();
var la_now = now.tz('America/Los_Angeles');
// print using la_now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Moment and Moment Timezone are both legacy libraries (and have been for *years*) that should be avoided unless you're already heavily reliant on them:

https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone